# Is it reasonable to say 'intricate with X' in the same sense one might say 'thick with flies' or 'vast with greed'?

Tags: prepositions, adjectives

Most 'Y with X' forms have Y as a verb - riddled with holes, filled with joy - but there are some commonly used examples where Y is an adjective. Is that a generally accepted construction that may be extended, or are those exceptions - isolated affectations that have slipped into general usage?

Comment: I thought "vast with greed" sounded odd, so I did a Google search. I regretted it...

Comment: Many X with Y forms are also nouns: green with envy; red with anger; purple with fury; black with emptiness. I know those are colors, but still. To accept intricate with, I'd have to see the phrasing of the entire sentence. Generally, I would not say that something is intricate with. I would use an adverb, intricately or adjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is idiomatic  ; the following page provides numerous examples of that usage : [intricate with](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22intricate%20with%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

I'd say that most examples are of recent origin but there are a few to be found already in the 19th century.

([ref. 1857](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Philosophy_of_the_Plays_of_Shakspere/llhZAAAAcAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22intricate+with%22&pg=PR81&printsec=frontcover))  in so many involutions , in passages so intricate with quips and puns and worthless trivialities , so uninviting or so marred with their superficial meanings , that no one would think of looking in them for anything of any value.

Comment: That's fantastic; thank you. I did do a search before asking, but Google seemed to misunderstand what I was looking for.